# Notepad++ auto complete html

Tags: notepad++

I am using autocomplete of Notepad++ and it's really good. But there is something that is really terrible compared with Dreamweaver autocomplete.

For example, if I type:

```
<div sty
```

the notepad++ will show me a list of autocomplete options. If I just hit ENTER notepad++ will make this:

```
<div style
```

Great, it works. But in Dreamweaver the same happens but it does this:

```
<div style=""
```

You see? Dreamweaver already adds que = and double quotes and insert the cursor right in the middle of "" so I can continue typing the content. How can I make notepad++ make this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there's no way Notepad++ can do this out of the box. But you might want to have a look at the Emmet plugin for Notepad++.

From their website:

> Emmet is a plugin for many popular text editors which greatly improves HTML & CSS workflow

More information on the [Emmet homepage](https://emmet.io/) and you can find the Notepad++ plugin on the [Emmet Github download page](https://github.com/emmetio/npp)